# default html character when load tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I load tinyMCE(jquery plugin based) in my textarea but i see default html in my box. when i send text, my data + this character insert to mysql. how to remove this characters?

html character :

```
<p><br></p>
```

load tinymce :

```
<script>
tinyMCE.init({ mode : "textareas", theme : "simple",directionality : "rtl"
,theme_advanced_buttons3 : "", theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",height:'100%'
,theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",});
</script>
```

mysql :

```
&lt;p&gt;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find these posts and articles useful:

- [validate textarea using tinyMCE - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012312/validate-textarea-using-tinymce-jquery)
- http://drupal.org/node/550428
- http://alastairc.ac/2010/03/removing-emtpy-html-tags-from-tinymce/